# Detecting QR codes in individual frames of a camera stream iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, computer-vision, qr-code

Im currently analysing frames of a camera video stream using OpenCV for Augmented Reality markers on iOS. I need to also be able to analyse each frame to see if they contain QR codes. Im currently using ZBarSDK for iOS to complete the task, but my performance has decreased from around 30fps to between 7-11fps when this is in use. I know ZBarSDK can be configured to increase frame rate by: only looking for QR codes and ignoring other barcodes, as well as adjusting the stride of each sweep but this has no real effect.

I noticed that ZXing is an alternative though it seems to be deprecated now and AVCaptureMetadataOutput from a AVCaptureSession is the way forward, but I cannot see if it is frame by frame processing.

Is there any other library that allows the processing of video streams frame by frame to detect QR codes on iOS? Or could anyone point me in the direction of maybe an OpenCV tutorial for writing QR code detection and QR content extraction from scratch?

Any help will be appreciated.